# Xcode 5.0 XCTest: ambiguous expansion of macro 'NULL'

Tags: objective-c, xcode, unit-testing, xcode5, c-preprocessor

I'm using Xcode 5. I have a OS X Framework / iOS static library project with mixed ObjC/C++ code and language dialects set to C11/C++11.

I added a *Cocoa Unit Testing Bundle* target which uses XCTest, I created one for both the iOS static library and the OS X framework.

This is the code I have and the error I get in both:

```
-(void) testExample
{
    NSObject* world = [NSObject new];

    world = nil;  <--- Ambiguous expansion of macro 'NULL'
}
```

Running the iOS test the compiler tells me it is using the definition of NULL from stddef.h (line 74, `((void*)0)`) and the other definition being in usr/include/stdlib.h (line 115, `__DARWIN_NULL`).

The OS X test fails points to usr/include/MacTypes.h (line 90, `__DARWIN_NULL`) with this time the alternative being in stddef.h (line 74, `((void*)0)`).

Google has nothing on this issue. I'm just like "Well, I guess it's just one of these days...".

Any clues as to what may be going on here, and how to fix it?

**UPDATE:**

The iOS tests not running were due to creating the iOS unit test bundle with the OS X "Cocoa Unit Testing Bundle". /me slap

The OS X testing issue persists though. But I have a hunch that being on OS X 10.9 (Mavericks) this may be related to a missing 10.9 SDK (Base SDK is set to 10.8).

Comment: I have same problem in `.m` file but warning go away after changes to `.mm`

Answer (score 12):

In your Build Settings for your test target, try setting "Enable Modules" to NO.

I've been having various kinds of trouble with test targets, all around preprocessor expansion. Doing this fixed things for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Add `-Wno-ambiguous-macro` to Xcode -> Build Settings -> Other C Flags